# Install and Configure apache Solr - Indexing failed on following nodes, missing required field entity type

Tags: php, solr, drupal-6, tomcat6, pressflow

I am working on Pressflow Drupal 6, Debian, Apache2, PHP 5.3.3 environment. Trying to set up Solr on it. Followed step 9. Install and Configure apache Solr http://groups.drupal.org/pantheon/mercurywiki

1. Install Tomcat6
2. Install Apache Solr
3. drush dl apachesolr
4. move Drupal specific config and schema files to solr/conf/

Now when I run cron

```
50% of the site has been indexed. There are 50 items left to index.
```

After that it fires an Apache Solr error (in 'Reports log entry')

```
Indexing failed on one of the following nodes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 
"400" Status: Document_tq3l64node1_missing_required_field_entity_type: Document_tq3l64node1_missing_required_field_entity_type


Error 400 

HTTP ERROR: 400Document [tq3l64/node/1] missing required field: entity_type
RequestURI=/solr/iexplore/updatePowered by Jetty://
```

Can you please help, why i am getting this issue and what is fix ?

Comment: Try to locate tq3l64/node/1 in your database and see what is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all, I got it working now. the only issue was schema.xml.

There is another Drupal 7 site running on same server which, so i need to change schema.xml. D7 and D6 schema files are different.

Now its working ..... thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

From the error it seems entity_type is a required field defined in the schema for the core.
The data fed to solr does not seem to have entity_type field and hence the documents fail to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better to configure apachesolr in multisiting way, it's easy. so each site will be using different schemes.
http://drupalconnect.com/blog/steve/configuring-apache-solr-multi-core-drupal-and-tomcat-ubuntu-910

I recommend you to do it.